# Slideup element and remove class on element that is already active

Tags: jquery

I have created a pretty simple menu system in which a panel will slide down when its respective tab has been clicked. Everything works fine but I am having a difficult time figuring out how to slide up the panel of the tab that is currently selected. In its current form it will just slide up and back down again if you click on the active tab. What I mean is if I click on the tab that is related to the currently shown panel, I want that panel to simply slide up and stay put.

Here is a fiddle and the js code that I have so far: 
http://jsfiddle.net/jayboodev737/h77Lzj90/

```
$(function () {

     $('.main_panel ul li').on('click', function () {

        panelToShow = $(this).attr('data-panel');



        $('.main_panel ul li.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');

        $('.main_panel .panel.active').slideUp(200, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('active novis');

            $('#' + panelToShow).slideDown(200, function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');

            });

        });
    });

});
```

It seems like an if statement that checks the class on the active tab would do the trick but I can't seem to get anything to work. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could check to see which section you are on by tracking some sort of string,boolean,int or div id compared to what is being clicked on, and  if those names match have it only slide up, else make it slide back down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check for the state of `$li`

```
$(function () {

    $('.main_panel ul li').on('click', function () {
        var panelToShow = $(this).data('panel');

        $('.main_panel ul li.active').not(this).removeClass('active');
        var $li = $(this).toggleClass('active');

        if ($li.hasClass('active')) {
            $('.main_panel .panel.active').slideUp(200, function () {
                $(this).removeClass('active novis');
                $('#' + panelToShow).slideDown(200, function () {
                    $(this).addClass('active');
                });
            });
        }else{
            $('#' + panelToShow).slideUp(200, function () {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/trv4pk24/)

Comment: That is perfect my friend. Thanks a lot for helping out!